# why we should post runnable to change some view behaviours

Tags: java, android, android-layout, material-design

i was wondering in some cases we should post runable to change a view behavior. for example i have a tabbed layout and i want to decide if i should make it scrollable or fixed based on screen size and tablaylout width. here is the code :

```java
mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        final TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(3, true);
        for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
            PersianTextView s = new PersianTextView(getApplicationContext());
            s.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            s.setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i));
            s.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            s.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.size));
            tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setCustomView(s);
        }
        if (tabLayout.getWidth() < UserDetails.this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels) {
            Log.d(TAG, "tabLayout.getMeasuredWidth(): " + tabLayout.getMeasuredWidth() + "  || UserDetails.this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels: " + UserDetails.this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels);
            tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);
        }
```

`tabLayout.getWidth()` in the above code returns zero. but if i do this it will work because `tabLayout.getWidth()` actually retrun a value:

```java
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        final TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(3, true);
        for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
            PersianTextView s = new PersianTextView(getApplicationContext());
            s.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            s.setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i));
            s.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            s.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.size));
            tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setCustomView(s);
        }
        tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (tabLayout.getWidth() < UserDetails.this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "tabLayout.getMeasuredWidth(): " + tabLayout.getMeasuredWidth() + "  || UserDetails.this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels: " + UserDetails.this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels);
                    tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Without the Runnable you're running your code probably inside some activity lifecycle callback, before the view has been positioned and measured properly. Hence the width == 0. When calling post() with a Runnable that code will be executed when the main looper handles your message, and that will happen after the previous messages (like measuring the views) are handled.